# Creating new dataframe per row in the dataframe after manipulation

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a single panda dataframe which I need to perform multiple operations on so that all of the data then relates to one of the rows. After the operations are complete, the dataframe need to be saved as a new dataframe referencing that row in the dataframe. This needs to be repeated for every row, so by the end I would have a new dataframe for each row in the dataframe.

```
 df
         A    B    C    D
    1    10   20   30   60
    2    20   10   10   20
    3    0    0    10   10
```

(dataframe manipulation)

```
    A    B    C    D
1    0    0    0    0 
2    10   -10  -20  -40
3    -10  -20  -20  -50
```

need this to be called: df1

(another manipulation to the original dataframe)

```
     A    B    C    D
1   -10   10   20   40
2    0    0    0    0
3   -20  -10   0   -10
```

need this to be saved as: df2
etc.....

any thoughts on how to do this.

here was my stab at it:

```
my_list = df["index"].tolist()
for i in my_list: 
    df + i = #the dataframe after manipulation
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the values of the index and use a Python dictionary to store the index value mapped to the dataframe.

```
df_dict = {}
for idx in df.index:
    df_current = # do some dataframe manipulation
    df_dict[idx] = df_current
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding them to a dictionary:

```
dataframes = {}
dataframes["df2"] = #dataframe after manipulation
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could store your dataframes in a list.

```
list_df = []
list_df.append(df)
list_df.append(df * 10)
list_df.append(df / 100)

print(list_df[0])

    A   B   C   D
1  10  20  30  60
2  20  10  10  20
3   0   0  10  10

print(list_df[1])
     A    B    C    D
1  100  200  300  600
2  200  100  100  200
3    0    0  100  100

print(list_df[2])

     A    B    C    D
1  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.6
2  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2
3  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1
```